# Ubuntu 18.04 and after-install luks encrypted home partition - cant load OS

Tags: mount, encryption, luks

I deployed Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop with home folder in separate partition (/home is /dev/sda6)

After installation I wanted to encrypt my home partition, for that I followed [this guide](https://linuxconfig.org/basic-guide-to-encrypting-linux-partitions-with-luks) to encrypt it.
Steps I did:

1. Boot live cd
2. Copy my home folder elsewhere (/backup)
3. Change it to luks type, encrypt with some passphrase as in the guide
4. Mount it as mentioned in the guide and copy back my home folder
5. Boot ubuntu

Obviously I didnt think this entirely...because ubuntu cant mount my home partition now.
I was able, via command line, to manually do mount commands and using the passphrase to mount it (/home2), and seeing the files...but how do I do it automatically, so that when I now boot my Ubuntu installation, it will decrypt my home folder for me, and let me see my files regularly?

Comment: I also tried to follow this guide: https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/encrypting-your-home-directory-using/ and while ubuntu boots up and shows my account if I want to login, it freezes once I hit enter to login